# Nodejs console.log outputs slow after many calls

Tags: node.js

I was doing some tests to see how console.log behaved when it had to handle millions of outputs and found that around the 4 million logs mark it slows down significantly and gets really bursty.  I can see it wait for quite a while, and then do a bunch of outputs at once.

Is there a reason for this slow down?  Can it be prevented?

Comment: do you plan to output 4million logs on console? why not use logging modules? also 4million at once on a production application is extremely rare to happen and should be considered bad practise

Comment: How `console.log` is being called is just as likely to be the problem as how many times it is called. For instance 4 million `setTimeout` calls used to simulate some sort of asynchronous system could just as well cause Node.js to choke.

Comment: I started down this path because I was thinking of using forever to save stdout logs in files automatically.  That lead to testing the limit, which lead to the question.  To answer you question, no I'm not planning on having 4 million logs to console in production.  I might log 4 million things to files though, is that still bad practice?

Comment: @Russbear Yes, that much IO will definitely kill performance. In case you really want to output that much data, you'll probably be better of using a database which uses memory.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting a feeling that a for loop from 1 to 4,000,000 console.log(i) isn't the best way to test this...

Comment: For some more info on the subject: https://github.com/bahamas10/node-log-buffer and from the manual: `The console functions are synchronous when the destination is a terminal or a file (to avoid lost messages in case of premature exit) and asynchronous when it's a pipe (to avoid blocking for long periods of time).`